# How can I update multi rows using wherein in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I update multi rows by id using whereIn I'm tried this, but doesn't work

```
 if (count($request->ids) > 0) {
            $downloaded = PreCreatedUser::whereIn('id', $request->ids)->update(['downloaded' => 1]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'message' => true,
            'data' => $downloaded
        ], 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a way to solve this, according to Laravel documentation, if you want to update multi rows by a specific data in this case an array of ids you can use for integer type data "whereIntegerInRaw", and this was my solution, and finally works.

```
    if (count($request->ids) > 0) {
        $downloaded = PreCreatedUser::whereIntegerInRaw('id', $request->ids)->update(['downloaded' => "1"]);
    }
    return response()->json([
        'message' => true,
        'data' => $downloaded
    ], 200);
```